# How to change this code to ARM assembly instructions?

Tags: assembly, arm

How to change this code to ARM assembly instructions?
I want to run this code in android kernel.But I don't know how to use ARM assembly instructions.

```
#define _syscall3(type,name,type1,arg1,type2,arg2,type3,arg3) \
type name(type1 arg1,type2 arg2,type3 arg3) \
{ \
long __res; \
__asm__ volatile ("int $0x80" \
       : "=a" (__res) \
       : "0" (__NR_##name),"b" ((long)(arg1)),"c" ((long)(arg2)), \
                "d" ((long)(arg3))); \
__syscall_return(type,__res); \
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: This code is for calling kernel syscalls from userspace. Are you sure, you want to call syscalls from kernel? This code can be implemented in ARM assembly in different ways, depending on ABI you are using.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how to use ARM assembly instructions.  We could write code for you, but you'll just be back here again asking for changes if you don't know how to use the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

What you need on ARM is the "software interrupt" instruction which is a rough equivalent of 'int' on x86:

```
swi 0  ;  0 is the interrupt vector for "syscall"
```

You can get an overview here: [OSDev Wiki on ARM](http://wiki.osdev.org/ARM_Overview)

The "hello, world" for ARM/Android can be found in this [post](http://peterdn.com/post/e28098Hello-World!e28099-in-ARM-assembly.aspx)

Comment: Thank you all the same.I find the a similar code on ARM,it's _syscall().So I don't have to modify that code above.